# How to align UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to build a `UICollectionView`as tag flow layout according to this topic: http://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/

It worked until the button action but there is one issue. As you can see at the picture below, custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s don't align correctly as like as at the topic. I did everything same but `FlowLayout.swift`

[image]

I want to make equal gaps between these cells. But they are aligning like this.

You can find `FlowLayout.swift` below.

Can someone tell me how can I fix it?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        var leftMargin : CGFloat = 0.0

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {
            let refAttributes = attributes
            // assign value if next row
            if (refAttributes.frame.origin.x == self.sectionInset.left) {
                leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
            } else {
                // set x position of attributes to current margin
                var newLeftAlignedFrame = refAttributes.frame
                newLeftAlignedFrame.origin.x = leftMargin
                refAttributes.frame = newLeftAlignedFrame
            }
            // calculate new value for current Fmargin
            leftMargin += refAttributes.frame.size.width + 8
            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(refAttributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

I changed the `UICollectionView`'s layout flow to custom and set `FlowLayout.swift` as UICollectionView's class.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread but the problem still persists. The code here helped me, to solve my problem but I created a more swifty and robust version of it. Already tested with Swift 5.1 and iOS 13.

```
// A collection view flow layout in which all items get left aligned
class LeftAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let originalAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }
        var leftMargin: CGFloat = 0.0
        var lastY: Int = 0
        return originalAttributes.map {
            let changedAttribute = $0
            // Check if start of a new row.
            // Center Y should be equal for all items on the same row
            if Int(changedAttribute.center.y.rounded()) != lastY {
                leftMargin = sectionInset.left
            }
            changedAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin
            lastY = Int(changedAttribute.center.y.rounded())
            leftMargin += changedAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            return changedAttribute
        }
    }
}
```